# jQuery chaining - Can I write cleaner code?

Tags: jquery

i'm slowly getting my head around jQuery and learning more each day, however I wonder if I can create cleaner code. I have heard of 'chaining' but am not sure how I apply this.

Below is a piece of working jQuery i've written, but although it works, can I reduce it/make it cleaner by chaining any of it?

The script removes a class on button click and adds another class whilst simultaneously hiding another div. At the end I have added on keydown events to use as well as button presses.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click(function(e) {
if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
$('#primary ul').removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
$('#primary ul .single-style-text').hide();

        }
else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
$('#primary ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
$('#primary ul .single-style-text').show();
        }
    });
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 71) { 
       $('#primary ul').removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
        $('#primary ul .single-style-text').hide();
   }
});
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 76) { 
       $('#primary ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
        $('#primary ul .single-style-text').show();
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: can it only be a stylelist(or list, dont know if) and grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    var ul = $('#primary ul');

    if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
        ul.removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid').find('.single-style-text').hide();
    } else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
        ul.removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist').find('.single-style-text').show();
    }

});

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var ul = $('#primary ul');

    if (e.which == 71) { 
        ul.removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid').find('.single-style-text').hide();
    } else if (e.which == 76) { 
        $('#primary ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist').find('.single-style-text').show();
    }
});
```

but if its just a list or a grid you want to toggle you can write it on two lines of code. (per event), like:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    var isGrid = $(this).hasClass('grid');
    $('#primary ul').removeClass(isGrid ? 'stylelist' : 'grid').addClass(isGrid ? 'grid' : 'list').find('.single-style-text')[isGrid ? 'hide' : 'show']();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There's one thing you can further chain in there:

```
$('#primary ul')
    .removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid')
    .find('.single-style-text').hide();
```

But the one thing that would make your code better would be to move that functionality into a function (even though this removes a little chaining):

```
function switchView(view) {
    var ul=$('#primary ul');
    ul.removeClass('stylelist').removeClass('grid');
    ul.addClass(view);
    var singleStyleText=ul.find('.single-style-text');
    singleStyleText.hide();
    if(view=='stylelist') {
        singleStyleText.show();
    }
}
```

Then your event handlers could look like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    if($('#primary ul').hasClass('grid')) {
        switchView('stylelist');
    }else{
        switchView('grid');
    }
    return false;
});
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 71) {
        switchView('grid');
    }else if(e.which == 76) {
        switchView('stylelist');
    }
});
```

Comment: ^ Choose maintainability over microefficiencies every time.

Answer (score 0):

A few cleanups...

To start, we can combine these two keydown events. There's really no need to have multiple calls, since what you're dealing with is a value from the event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click(function(e) {
  if($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    $('#primary ul').removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
    $('#primary ul .single-style-text').hide();
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
    $('#primary ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
    $('#primary ul .single-style-text').show();
  }
});

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 71) { 
       $('#primary ul').removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
        $('#primary ul .single-style-text').hide();
   }
   if (e.which == 76) { 
        $('#primary ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
        $('#primary ul .single-style-text').show();
   }
});
</script>
```

Now, you're doing a lot of repetitive work... How about minimizing that by wrapping that up in a function?

Now, I may have gotten a bit carried away...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click( swapClasses() );

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 71) { 
      $('#primary ul').removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
      $('#primary ul .single-style-text').hide();
   }
   else if (e.which == 76) { 
      $('#primary ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
      $('#primary ul .single-style-text').show();
   }
});

swapClasses = function() {
  $('#primary ul').toggleClass( 'stylelist' ).toggleClass( 'grid' );
  $('#primary ul .single-style-text').toggle( showOrHide );
}
</script>
```

Looks a wee bit cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

As far as chaining goes, i don't think there's much to change around. A few things that i would change though...

1. Where is your document.ready ?
2. Cache your selectors so they can be reused.
3. Use more specific selectors. Instead of just button specify the class too.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
       var primary = $('#primary ul'); 
       var single_style_text = primary.find('.single-style-text'); 

       $('button.grid','button.list').click(function(e) {
           if ( $(this).hasClass('grid') ) {
               primary.removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
               single_style_text.hide();

           }
           else if( $(this).hasClass('list') ) {
               primary.removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
               single_style_text.show();
           }
       });

       $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
          if (e.which == 76) { 
               primary.removeClass('grid').addClass('stylelist');
               single_style_text.show();
          }

          if (e.which == 71) { 
              primary.removeClass('stylelist').addClass('grid');
               single_style_text.hide();
          }
       });
   }) 
   </script>
   ```